# "Required-Stop:" line in System-V type init script LSB header

Tags: init-script, init, sysvinit

I wrote a daemon which watches for files in certain directory and if a new file is copied to this directory, then it is committed to SVN. New files appear in this directory only if remote devices copy files there over `scp`. Now I would like to create a System-V init script for this daemon in OpenSUSE 11.4. It's clear that `Required-Start:` line should contain only the `$sshd` boot facility as this ensures that local file-system is mounted, networking is operational and `sshd` is started. Those three boot facilities are prerequisites for the daemon, i.e. there is no point to start the daemon if `sshd` is not operational and thus it is impossible that it receives new files over `scp`. However, I'm bit puzzled how should I configure the `Required-Stop:` line, which lists any boot facilities which should **NOT** be stopped before shutting down the daemon. It looks logical to me to have local file systems mounted and networking operational(for uploading the files to SVN) while `sshd` is stopped(for not receiving any new files) before the daemon is stopped. `Required-Stop: $sshd` could create a situation where daemon is stopped while a new file is received over `scp` before the `sshd` is stopped.

So in a nutshell, following approach seems to be most logical to me:

```
# Required-Start: $sshd
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts in the section on `Required-Stop`

> Normally you would include here the same facilities as for the
>   Required-Start keyword.

Having this script running before `ssh` starts isn't a problem like you suggested in the OP it just means this daemon will be waiting for files that will never appear until `ssh` starts.  This script, however, definitely does need the functionality of `$local_fs` and `$network` so I would use the following two lines

```
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network
```